# Replicate interpolation for multiple variables

Tags: loops, interpolation, stata, replication

I am interpolating multiple variables in Stata, but don't know how to do it efficiently.

My data looks like this

| Country | Year | v_country_1 | v_country_2 | v_country_3 | ... | v_country_234 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | 2000 | 1005 | 1051 | 1052 | --- | 1120 |
| Canada | 2001 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Canada | 2002 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Canada | 2003 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Canada | 2004 | 2000 | 3500 | 500 | --- | 10562 |
| Korea | 2000 | 1005 | 1051 | 1052 | --- | 1120 |
| Korea | 2001 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Korea | 2002 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Korea | 2003 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Korea | 2004 | 2000 | 3500 | 500 | --- | 10562 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | --- | .... |
| Uganda | 2000 | 1005 | 1051 | 1052 | --- | 1120 |
| Uganda | 2001 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Uganda | 2002 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Uganda | 2003 |  |  |  | --- |  |
| Uganda | 2004 | 2000 | 3500 | 500 | --- | 10562 |

As you can see my data includes multiple countries. So, I need to interpolate the variables by country.

I can interpolate the one variable very easily by using the code :

```
by cow: ipolate v_country_1 year, gen(v_country_1_ipo)
```

But, I have 234 variables... so it is almost impossible to replicate this work by hand.

Could you please teach me how to do it?
(I know there is a command foreach that is meant to do replication.)

Answer (score 1):

```
ds v_country_*

foreach x in `r(varlist)' {
    by country: ipolate `x' year, gen(`x'_ipo)
}

// OR

forvalues i = 1/234 {
    by country: ipolate v_country_`i' year, gen(v_country_`i'_ipo)
}
```

Check out `help ds` and `help forvalues` or `help foreach` for further details.

Comment: `foreach x of var v_country_*` would work, making the `ds` call unnecessary.